# What's the correct approach to configure Brunch to output multiple HTML/JS files from one template file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, npm, brunch

Here's my situation - I have multiple ad units to create, each of different sizes and different animations.

I'm trying to run a single Brunch watch server to handle the following:

- Execute some **pre-processes** (ie: use TexturePacker to publish CSS/LESS and PNG atlas).
- Copy content of app/assets/index.html to temporary file / buffer (because it uses a few `{{handle-bar-like}}` placeholder tags to be replaced by each files' configuration).
- Replace placeholder tags for ad's width, height, border width, border height, title & filename, etc.
- Inline the JS & CSS specific to that ad (located in `app/en_???x???_etc/`) with the temporary file / buffer (this pastes the JS and CSS in respective commented lines from the template index.html file).
- Execute some **post-processes** (ie: string replacements / cleanup, etc.)

My dilemma is that I'm not exactly sure where should I write the configuration & file- & folder-lookups code.

Can I just drop some code in `brunch-config.js` before the `module.exports` object is defined (or put it in a separate file that the config file `requires(...)` before the config is defined)?

And what about defining the pre- & post-processes calls? I'm aware that `beforeBrunch` and `afterBrunch` exists, but I'm not exactly sure if it'll get called before & after each index.html file copies, or before everything AND after everything as been copied (if that makes sense). And to make matters more complex, each of those pre- & post-process calls may need to be slightly different to supply the filenames for each JS, CSS, atlas.png outputs.

I've achieved a setup similar to this with Haxe (which in this case acted as a command-line companion), but if I can narrow-down this workflow to only use NodeJS / NPM modules, it'll make my clients' lives a lot easier when sharing projects with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Brunch contrib here. Yes, you can drop your code in your brunch-config. `beforeBrunch/afterBrunch` plugins are for running shell commands. In case you want to run your own code, just use brunch's `preCompile`/`onCompile` callbacks. `preCompile` is called before anything is compiled/copied, `onCompile` is run after everything is compiled and assets are copied to public.

I'm not sure if I understand your flow perfectly, but this would definitely be possible:

1. use a `preCompile` callback and/or `beforeBrunch` plugin to copy `app/assets/index.html` to `app/something/template.hbs` for each ad
2. use a *modified* version of [`static-handlebars-brunch`](https://github.com/bloudermilk/static-handlebars-brunch/blob/master/src/index.coffee) (to additionally pass a file path or something to the context getter function, because this one doesn't do it)
3. use a `onCompile` callback and/or `afterBrunch` plugin to inline stylesheets and do whatever else you might need

Do you think this is something that would work for your case? Did I miss anything?

I do have to admit that in complex workflow scenarios, brunch might be not the optimal solution to express these by itself, given its simplistic nature, but it is great for most common front-end development use-cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to call `node myscript.js before` and `node myscript.js after` on beforeBrunch/afterBrunch respectively, but there may be more information I need to get this working a bit more smoothly with minimal configuration. Mind if I reach you via email / Slack if possible?

Comment: @bigp sure, use my email from GitHub